# How to compare two JSON files in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm new to Azure data factory. I want to compare two json files through azure data factory. We need to get new list of id's in current JSON file which are not in previous JSON file. Below are the two sample JSON files.

**Previous JSON file:**

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "4e10aa02d0b945ae9dcf5cb9ded9a083"
    },
    {
      "id": "cbc414db-4d08-48f2-8fb7-748c5da45ca9"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Current JSON file**:

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "4e10aa02d0b945ae9dcf5cb9ded9a083"
    },
    {
      "id": "cbc414db-4d08-48f2-8fb7-748c5da45ca9"
    },
    {
      "id": "5ea951e3-88d7-40b4-9e3f-d787b94a43c8"
    }
  ]
}
```

New id's has to perform one activity and old id's has to perform another activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a **IfCondition Activity**

[image]

If expression:

```
@equals(activity('Lookup1').output.value,activity('Lookup2').output.value)
```

[image]

Further I have used **Fail Activity** for False condition for better visibility.

[image]

--

### Lookup1 Activity --> Json1.json

[image]

### Lookup2 Activity --> Json2.json

[image]

Comment: This solution does not give a list of new IDs. The final result should be a list or file which contains the new record "id": "5ea951e3-88d7-40b4-9e3f-d787b94a43c8".

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a single Filter Activity.
I have assigned two parameters "Old_json" and "New_json" for your Previous Json and Current Json files respectively.
In the settings of Filter activity,

- Items: @pipeline().parameters.New_json.values
- Condition: @not(contains(pipeline().parameters.Old_Json.values,item()))

So, this filter activity goes through each item in New json, and checks if they are present in the old json. If not present, then will give that as an output.

[Output of the filter activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Aq4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @KarthikBhyresh-MT for a helpful answer.

Just to add, if (like me) you want to compare two files (or in my case, a file with the output of a SQL query), but **don't care about the order of the records**, you can do this using a **ForEach** activity.  This also has the benefit of allowing a more specific error message in the case of a difference between the files.

[image: Comparison pipeline]

My first **If Condition** checks the two files have the same row count, with the expression:

```
@equals(activity('Select from SQL').output.count, activity('Lookup from CSV').output.count)
```

The False branch leads to a **Fail** activity with message:

```
@concat(pipeline().parameters.TestName, ': CSV has ', string(activity('Lookup from CSV').output.count), ' records but SQL query returned ', string(activity('Select from SQL').output.count))
```

If this succeeds, flow passes to a **ForEach**, iterating through items:

```
@activity('Lookup from CSV').output.value
```

... which contains an **If Condition** with expression:

```
@contains(string(activity('Select from SQL').output.value), string(item()))
```

[image: If Condition]

The False branch for that **If Condition** contains an **Append variable** activity, which appends to a variable I've added to the pipeline called `MismatchedRecords`.  The Value appended is:

```
@item()
```

Following the **ForEach**, a final **If Condition** then checks whether `MismatchedRecords` contains any items:

```
@equals(length(variables('MismatchedRecords')), 0)
```

... and the False branch contains another **Fail** activity, with message:

```
@concat(string(length(variables('MismatchedRecords'))), ' records from CSV not found in SQL. Missing records: ', string(variables('MismatchedRecords')), ' SQL output: ', string(activity('Select from SQL').output.value))
```

The message contains specific information about the records which could not be matched, to allow further investigation.